# nested initializer_list initialization failing when I switch from basic array types to custom types

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I'm building a generic mathematical vector class for fun and I'm not sure what is wrong with my interface that this initializer_list usage breaks down:

```
struct Vertex {
    // Compiles and works fine with these two lines
    //float pos[2];
    //float color[3];

    // Does not compile with these lines
    Vector2 pos;
    Vector3 color;
};

const std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {
    { {  0.0f, -0.5f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },
    { {  0.5f,  0.5f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f } },
    { { -0.5f,  0.5f }, { 1.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f } }
};
```

Core vector implementation bits:

```
template <int size>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(const std::initializer_list<float>& values) : _data(values) {}

    Vector<size>& operator=(const std::initializer_list<float>& values)
    {
        _data = values;
        return *this;
    }

    // Code compiles again if I make this array public
private:
    float _data[size];
};

typedef Vector<2> Vector2;
typedef Vector<3> Vector3;
```

The error I'm receiving (building with VS2019):

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<Vertex,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
error C2440:         with
error C2440:         [
error C2440:             _Ty=Vertex
error C2440:         ]
message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

EDIT

As someone pointed out this actually does compile - I forgot I had attempted to alias the standard vector types:

```
template <> 
class Vector<2> 
{ 
    union 
    { 
        float _data[2];
        struct 
        { 
            float X, Y; 
        }; 
    }; 
};

template <>
class Vector<3>
{
    union
    {
        float _data[3];
        struct
        {
            float X, Y, Z;
        };
        struct
        {
            float R, G, B;
        };
    };
};
```

It looks like this was causing the error although I'm not sure the proper way to do this aliasing just yet...

Comment: After fixing a couple unrelated errors, [I cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/sC4Gqp).

Comment: A note on those unrelated errors Nathan Oliver mentions: You're going to have to work a bit harder to get those initializer lists into the arrays.

Comment: You're right, I fixed that up locally - I had forgotten I had put in an attempt to alias my vector data for Vector2 and Vector3.  Added that code in above.

Comment: Do note that using unions like you want to is undefined behavior.  Most/all implementations will "do the right thing", but you have no guarantee that it will.